# I can't create the Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I try to create the AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment, I received the following error,

```
LaunchWaitCondition failed. The expected number of EC2 instances were not initialized 
within the given time. Rebuild the environment. If this persists, contact support.
```

[image]

Wahts the issue here?

Comment: This is quite hard to debug given the information we have at hand. Possibly your account has reached the limit for the given EC2 instance. I suggest reaching out to AWS support to gain some more information on the error you run into.

Comment: Are you using AutoScaling life cycle hooks? What are you doing during wait condition?

Comment: You need to check your account limits in EC2 and Load Balancers. What min-max EC2 count have you given in the beanstalk? For starters terminate a few existing EC2 instances and try again.